# About XAML, code-behind and MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, code-behind

Assume I have the view with DataGrid. Also I have the view-model with the collection of some objects. DataGrid binds to the collection. The target is setting the color of row depends on value of object's property. Regarding on MVVM is it right way to do it in code-behind like code below ?

```
private void ScheduleGrid_OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var schedule = e.Row.DataContext as OrderScheduleModel;
    if(schedule==null)
        return;
    if (schedule.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || schedule.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x90, 0xee, 0x90));
    }
}
```

I know I could create behavior, attached property, style, etc. But 
basically, does MVVM allow to do manipulations with view  *_based_on_view-model_* in code-behind ?

Comment: I prefer pushing most of the code into ViewModel. For your case you can remove this code-behind logic by using converters in xaml at the time of binding RowBackground property of DataGrid. Such converter would accept OrderScheduleModel.Date as parameter and return the SolidColorBrush.

Comment: @dotnetkid, RowBackground  is for all rows. OrderScheduleModel is an element of the collection, view-model of a row. I need to highlight only weekend rows. It can be implemented with DataGrid.RowStyle. But I don't khow how to save default color for  non-weekend rows. With style I could highlight weekends by one color, other days - by other color, but by default rows are highlited by different colors (gray- white ,odd - white).

Comment: See my code below. It highlights individual row based on condition using converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of MVVM, as a pattern, is to separate view from view model and model.

The bunch of MVVM and XAML assumes, that view and view model use data binding to communicate each other. Data binding is, probably, the *best* way, but not the *only* way. Until your code doesn't bring UI logic into VM and vice versa, this is still MVVM.

From this point, code sample from the question is OK.

Comment: But there UI logic uses view-model, so it is not separated from. I can't test that UI without view-model. I'm not right ?

Comment: UI logic uses VM anyway. This is the nature of VM - to prepare data in the way, convenient to display in UI. This code: `Background="{Binding MyBackgroundProperty}"` is also uses VM. The difference is that when your `DataContext == null`, with  binding you'll get default value for `Background `, because `Binding` class handles this case, while your code will throw NRE. Try do describe UI, using data binding only, then try to test this UI *without* data context.

Comment: "Separation" doesn't mean, that M, V, and VM are totally isolated from each other. It means, that their logic are not mixed, and they are coupled as loosely, as it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I sure you right. To make the coupling looser we can use VM from view via interface.

Answer (score 1):

**Assume**:

1. Person - Model class with Name and Dob props.
2. People - ObservableCollection of Person objects.
3. Logic is to highlight rows which contain a Person with birth year prior to 2000.

**Converter**:

```
public class DobToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

            var dob = (DateTime)value;

            if (dob.Year <= 2000)
            {
                brush.Color = Colors.LightGray;
            }

            return brush;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DobToColorConverter x:Key="DobToColor" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Dob, Converter={StaticResource DobToColor}}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for example ! But there all rows after 2000 are highlited too, by transparent color instead of default color. Or does transparent color not override default color ?

Comment: Transparent is not a color itself. Also the rows after 2000 are not highlighted. You can those rows are of same color as window body outside of data grid boundaries. You see it at some shade due to my custom windows OS theme (may be).

Comment: Sorry, but I've just tried - transparent color overrides default color. How I've said above, by  default (in Silverlight) rows are highlited by different colors (gray- white ,odd - white), not same color as window body outside. With your approach all rows after 2000 (non-weekends in my case) have no color, it's wrong.

Comment: As variant, we could pass default color to converter as parameter and use it instead of transparent. ... ConverterParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Background} ... but I not sure it works.

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work :)  Maybe in WPF it looks like it works but not in Silverlight.